# Fax header transmission

Tags: headers, fax

I am trying to understand the fax protocol better.

The question is, when a fax header is specified in a fax machine, does the machine:

a. Transmit the time/pagecount/etc separately from the visual data of the pages

b. "Preprint" the time/pagecount into the visual data, thus altering the sent image from the scanned original.

Is it A or B?

Comment: [Fax has a multitude of protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T.38#Related_standards) so unless you specify which you probably won't find the answer you're looking for. Aside from that it's probably [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would keep it here even though it's slightly offtopic, as there is probably no other place for such questions at all. Note that all current (non-withdrawn) fax specifications [are freely available](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T/en). They don't seem to mention anything except plain visual data transmission.

Comment: In other news this evening, there are still fax machines.